# Guide to use Yolo with gpu c#

Tags: c#, gpu, artificial-intelligence, yolo, yolov5

I've been trying to find a tutorial or something on how to make yolo c# use gpu instead of cpu, I always find that it says that it works on both cpu and gpu but no one ever says how to use the gpu since it always uses cpu for me. Here's my code with yolo v5 c#. It doesn't really matter for me if it uses yolo v5 just that it uses gpu. [Tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuxuj.png) I found that tutorial but i can't even find the download for Nvidia cuDNN v7.6.3 for CUDA 10.1. It feels very unclear on how to use it with gpu please help me :D

```cs
            var image = pictureBox1.Image;

            var scorer = new YoloScorer<YoloCocoP5Model>("Assets/Weights/yolov5n.onnx");

            List<YoloPrediction> predictions = scorer.Predict(image);

            var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);

            foreach (var prediction in predictions) // iterate predictions to draw results
            {

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);

                    prediction.Label.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);

                    double score = Math.Round(prediction.Score, 2);

                    graphics.DrawRectangles(new Pen(prediction.Label.Color, 1),
                        new[] { prediction.Rectangle });

                    var (x, y) = (prediction.Rectangle.X - 3, prediction.Rectangle.Y - 23);

                    graphics.DrawString($"{prediction.Label.Name} ({score})",
                        new Font("Consolas", 16, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), new SolidBrush(prediction.Label.Color),
                        new PointF(x, y));
                    pictureBox1.Image = image;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you are going to use scorer you need an option set.

```
        //https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/execution-providers/CUDA-ExecutionProvider.html

        bool initResult = false;

        var cudaProviderOptions = new Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.OrtCUDAProviderOptions(); // Dispose this finally

        var providerOptionsDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        providerOptionsDict["device_id"] = "0";
        providerOptionsDict["gpu_mem_limit"] = "2147483648";
        providerOptionsDict["arena_extend_strategy"] = "kSameAsRequested";

        /*
            cudnn_conv_algo_search
            The type of search done for cuDNN convolution algorithms.

            Value   Description
            EXHAUSTIVE (0)  expensive exhaustive benchmarking using cudnnFindConvolutionForwardAlgorithmEx
            HEURISTIC (1)   lightweight heuristic based search using cudnnGetConvolutionForwardAlgorithm_v7
            DEFAULT (2) default algorithm using CUDNN_CONVOLUTION_FWD_ALGO_IMPLICIT_PRECOMP_GEMM
            Default value: EXHAUSTIVE
        */
        providerOptionsDict["cudnn_conv_algo_search"] = "DEFAULT";

        /*
            do_copy_in_default_stream

            Whether to do copies in the default stream or use separate streams. The recommended setting is true. If false, there are race conditions and possibly better performance.
            Default value: true
        */
        providerOptionsDict["do_copy_in_default_stream"] = "1";

        /*
            cudnn_conv_use_max_workspace
            Check tuning performance for convolution heavy models for details on what this flag does. This flag is only supported from the V2 version of the provider options struct when used using the C API. The V2 provider options struct can be created using this and updated using this. Please take a look at the sample below for an example.

            Default value: 0
        */
        providerOptionsDict["cudnn_conv_use_max_workspace"] = "1";

        /*
            cudnn_conv1d_pad_to_nc1d
            Check convolution input padding in the CUDA EP for details on what this flag does. This flag is only supported from the V2 version of the provider options struct when used using the C API. The V2 provider options struct can be created using this and updated using this. Please take a look at the sample below for an example.

            Default value: 0
        */
        providerOptionsDict["cudnn_conv1d_pad_to_nc1d"] = "1";


        cudaProviderOptions.UpdateOptions(providerOptionsDict);
        options = SessionOptions.MakeSessionOptionWithCudaProvider(cudaProviderOptions);  // Dispose this finally        

            if (options != null)
            {
                // check yolo model file is accesible
                if (File.Exists(yoloModelFile))
                {
                    scorer = new YoloScorer<YoloCocoP5Model>(yoloModelFile, options);
                    initResult = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    DebugMessage("Yolo model ONNX file (" + yoloModelFile + ") is missing!\r\n", 2);
                }
            }
            else
                DebugMessage("Yolo instance initializing error! Session options are empty!\r\n", 2);
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).